# SQL Average of grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, average

I am trying to get our students' average scores for the tasks of responsibility and collaboration. The problem is that the responsibility and collaboration tasks can be called different things-like "Collaboration in Music" and "Collaboration in Math", but they still have either 'responsibility' or 'collaboration' in their names. So when I run the query below, I get multiple results for tasks related to collaboration and multiple results for responsibility tasks. I need one average for responsibility and one for collaboration. Any suggestions? I have SQL Server.

```
SELECT gradingscores.task AS task, 
       avg(Cast(gradingscores.score AS decimal) as averages 
FROM gradingscores 
WHERE    isnumeric(gradingscores.score) = 1
  AND    task LIKE %responsibility% 
   OR    task LIKE %collaboration%
```

So my results look like:

Task                             Averages
Responsibility in Music           4.0
Responsibility in Math            3.5
Responsibility n English          3.0
Collaboration in Music            3.5
Collaboration in Art              2.5

I would like my results to look like:

Task             Averages
Responsibility   4.0
Collaboration    3.5

The grading scores are also in varchar and need to be converted to numbers, discounting any non-numeric data.

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data and expected result to see what you need.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: **Do not use float** unless you're performing statistical sampling and understand the loss of precision that this comes with. **Use decimal at all times in computing until you understand this issue**. Float is an inexact data type that uses base 2 exponents to represent numbers, thus cannot exactly represent decimal numbers, and can yield issues where a value expected as (say) 5 would appear as 4.99999999.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I just needed to drop the task name from the Select statement and run separate queries for the responsibility and collaboration grades. That way it automatically groups all of the tasks that have responsibility or collaboration in them.

```
SELECT avg(Cast(gradingscores.score AS decimal) as averages 
FROM gradingscores 
WHERE    isnumeric(gradingscores.score) = 1
         AND task LIKE %responsibility%
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to group by the first 14 letters of the task, with an rtrim to get rid of the extra space on collaboration ( 13 letters )

The 'where' will make sure it's only going to get the entries that are collaboration or responsibility.

```
SELECT   RTRIM(LEFT(gradingscores.task, 14) AS task, 
         cast(avg(Cast(gradingscores.score AS decimal(10,1)) as decimal(10,1)) as averages 
FROM     gradingscores 
WHERE    isnumeric(gradingscores.score) = 1
  AND    task LIKE 'responsibility%' 
   OR    task LIKE 'collaboration%'
GROUP BY RTRIM(LEFT(gradingscores.task, 14)
```